# Authenticate network credential to access SharePoint site on client object model

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, networkcredentials

I am working to small app, that is require to bring all users in all groups of given site. I have two sites; SharePoint 2010 running on premisses and SharePoint 2013 online. I am getting credential error...

```
{"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}
```

### code.

```
 public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string _siteURL = "https://intranet.co.uk";

        NetworkCredential _myCredentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "https://intranet");

        ClientContext _clientContext = new ClientContext(_siteURL);

        _clientContext.Credentials = _myCredentials;

        Web _MyWebSite = _clientContext.Web;

        GroupCollection _GroupCollection = _MyWebSite.SiteGroups;

        _clientContext.Load(_GroupCollection);

        _clientContext.Load(_GroupCollection,
                             groups => groups.Include(group => group.Users)
             );

        _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (Group _group in _GroupCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Group Id   " + _group.Id + "     Group Title  " + _group.Title);

            UserCollection _userCollection = _group.Users;

            foreach (User _user in _userCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Group ID: {0} Group Title: {1} User: {2} Login Name: {3}", _user.Title, _user.LoginName);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n.......................................");
        }

        Console.Read();

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your credentials are wrong, espacially your domain.

```
NetworkCredential _myCredentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "https://intranet");
```

Your useraccount is specified as `domain\username` and I doubt your domainname would be `https://intranet`, but rather `companyname`. If you are not sure, ask your Exchange administrator.

What you are looking for is something analog to this:

```
NetworkCredential _myCredentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "companydomain");
//OR
NetworkCredential _myCredentials = new NetworkCredential(@"companydomain\user", "password");
```

Comment: i have feelings that i am doing something wrong on credentials details ... i try different options and come bk... many thanks in advance for helping me

Comment: does it matter that SharePoint 2010 is running on premisses ... can i use same approach as you have define????????

Comment: Your code is fine. The only problem you have is, that you used the wrong value for the `domain` in Credentials. If you can reach your `_siteUrl` in your browser, you can also reach it in code.

Comment: does it seems correct???          NetworkCredential _myCredentials = new NetworkCredential(@"dir\myUserName", "xyz", "intranet.xyz.ac.uk");

Comment: No. if `dir` is your domain it is either 1. `"dir\myUserName", "xyz"` OR: 2. "myUserName", "xyz", "dir". Ask your administrators what your domain is, then use what they tell you and enter it as your domain

Comment: I have use option 1 with dir\myUserName", "xyz and it works .... many thanks once again for helping me