# Unable to edit word document online using o365 MS Graph API getPreviewLinkWithEdit

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

Using **o365 MS Graph API** to edit word document online. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-preview?view=graph-rest-beta This feature was working till 22nd JAN 2021. We are not able to edit document online from 27th JAN.

**Code:**

```
public static String getPreviewLinkWithEdit(String itemId, InlineEditorConfig config, boolean editFlag) throws JSONException {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.add(AUTHORIZATION, BEARER + config.getAccessToken());
        
        String test = TEST;
        
        if (!editFlag) {
            test = TEST_WITHOUT_EDIT;
        }

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(test, headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(HTTPS_GRAPH_BASE_URL_BETA + itemId + PREVIEW,
                HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
        return (null != response.getBody()
                && null != new JSONObject(response.getBody()).getString(GET_URL_STRING)
                        ? new JSONObject(response.getBody()).getString(GET_URL_STRING)
                        : "");
    }
```

Displaying the MS Word web URL in `iframe`:

```
<iframe id="imagepgframe" src="https://purushothamchowdary-my.sharepoint.com/personal/purushotham_purushothamchowdary_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/PreAuth.aspx?sourcedoc={289e7b7a-e5d3-43dc-957a-5564ca9faeb9}&action=edit#access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkcydDJKYzlkMVZ6RkdjdzZUZy02YUhZVXk2VSJ9%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%2EOjcVqrRRrFrG6YNacnl2h32Hd1exc30YMGhrTdhJ2nSxhciaYqrMWkhLUMz7hDxyONMtgHVUzBty%2DNP2WUtDibf%2DKzOCTTW9aF01ytp%5FQTqIikpdDLUkyXQwDuJQzKuZh8vjxSXF5jfYtoK7JyqUNXZfllozebrqXe80arK%2DTNvvqAk3tOqF5yBedEYW0KrIIyFlyPNXNMyxdGBNEvRjMpMBqzE0Pn3wBiWeh6q4Bx8qSCYE9HwObPDUNtw%2DtCZh%2DFx6suS%5F3kuntWjyxKOqYRfYWpt%5FrWwFCxbFvWwThG5JcT1RUWHi0vdvA9%2DVGn%5FMUqxuKr9BQjUaQC9SFIhaMw"></iframe>
```

The word document file is getting uploaded to OneDrive. In application getting the web URL to open the word document in browser. The application java code works fine without giving any error .

Preview Link :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/01ZPAXLBD2POPCRU7F3RBZK6SVMTFJ7LVZ/preview
```

In `iframe` bellow error getting displayed:

[image: Error in iframe mapped to web URL of word document]

[image]

Error in browser console:

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://word-edit.officeapps.live.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://sheethaljav-my.sharepoint.com').

[image]

**Cookie:**

[image]

Comment: (1) Outside of your code, try repro the issue with Graph explorer or POSTMAN. This will help you to isolate the issue. (2) Share the detailed error response that you receive as part of response (it will contain the requestid, timestamp) as well. (3) Try outside of iframe as well to see if it works.

Comment: 1. Outside code and the issue is not with the Graph explorer or POSTMAN, As it is giving the web URL to edit the document online. 2. Not getting any error except the error dialog in the post. 3. Outside `iframe` if I add the URL in browser directly it is working able to edit the word document.

Comment: Thanks @Mihir. Thats what i thought it earlier and asked to isolate the issue outside of iframe. So the issue sounds like its with iframe. Will see if there is any known issues around it.

Comment: @Dev I have added sample code to the post  and the code we are using to display in `iframe` . Please help me. This functionality was working till last Friday. Without any change to code it is not working from last 2days.

Comment: @Dev After analysis found that when I login to share point manually in browser. Then access the web URL using graph API it is opening the word document and in frame also that web URL is working. The login information of share point stored in browser cookie. But everything was working before with only access token. Now Is there any API to authenticate share point programmatically. We are using JAVA programming language with REST API

Answer (score 0):

Upon your description, there's no error message in your java code, so maybe you can debug your code to get the real 'GET_URL_STRING' to check if it has got the correct link url.

And I have test the api in api test tool, with ropc flow to get an access token and then calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/【itemid】/preview'(according to your code, I assumed you're using this one) and I got the error of 'notAllowed', then I delete the suffix '/preview' and it replied with the url. So could you pls add more details on your debug result?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am also getting the URL using post man and from our application also. When displaying this URL using a `iframe` the word editor not loaded. I have update to post the URL mapping in `iframe` src attribute and also added the preview URL.

Comment: Now, you can get the url successfully, and the problems left is show content in an iframe, so have you checked if there's some error in the browser's console platform(F12)? I tried to create an html file and added iframe, and I got an error like 'Refused to display 'https://xxxxx' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.'

Comment: Added Console log screen-shot to the post.

Comment: are you able to view the document in `iframe`.

Comment: Also in browser console getting the error as : _Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://word-edit.officeapps.live.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://sheethaljav-my.sharepoint.com')._

Comment: To tell you the truth that I haven't dealt with the error I mentioned  above when creating iframe till now. And I found some saying which tells iframe is forbidden for security problems but you said that everything's ok until some days before, that's really a good question and I need to keep searching solutions tomorrow. And if you got the answer, pls post it in this question so that it may help others, I really found severial simialr questions in stack overflow with no correct answers.

Comment: After analysis found that when I login to share point manually in browser. Then access the web URL using graph API it is opening the word document and in frame also that web URL is working. The login information of share point stored in browser cookie. But everything was working before with only access token. Now Is there any API to authenticate share point programmatically.

Comment: You mean that you wanna to get login information by program and stored it in browser cookie so that you can open word document in iframe? If so, could you pls tell me what messages are stored in cookie? In my opinion, share point is also integrated with azure ad to achieve authentication.

Comment: Yes I wanna login to https://purushothamchowdary-my.sharepoint.com/ through a program and store information in a cookie. I added the screen-shot of cookie to the post.

Comment: @Mihir Hi, can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929259/authenticate-network-credential-to-access-sharepoint-site-on-client-object-model) help you?